# Python Regex to find all characters between two index values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

Looking for a way to use a Python regex to extract all the characters in a string between to indexes. My code is below:

```
import re

txt = "Hula hoops are fun."
x = re.search(r"hoops", txt)
c = x.span()
a = c[0]
b = c[1]

print(a) # prints 5
print(b) # prints 10

txt2 = "Hula loops are fun."

z = re.???(a, b, txt2) #<------ Incorrect
print(z)
```

What I am trying to figure out is to somehow use `a` and `b` to get `z = "loops"` in `txt2` (the rewrite of `txt`). Is there a python regex command to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `z = txt[a:b]` to extract all characters between `a` and `b` indices.

Comment: I came up with a solution (below), but it is long because it has to explicitly go through a list conversion and back to a string.  I like your version better here because it is more brief. Ty!

Answer (score 1):

Why not using slices(the obvious way)?

```py
z = txt2[a:b]
print(z)  # loops
```

If you *really* want to use regex, you need to consume a `.` character `a` times to reach `a` because Regex doesn't have indexing directly. Then get the next `b - a` characters. In your case you end up with `(?<=.{5}).{5}` pattern. `(?<=.{5})` part is a positive lookbehind assertion.

```py
pat = rf"(?<=.{{{str(a)}}}).{{{str(b - a)}}}"
print(re.search(pat, txt2))
```

output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(5, 10), match='loops'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

txt = "Hula hoops are fun."
x = re.search(r"hoops", txt)
c = x.span()
a = c[0]
b = c[1]

print(a) # prints 5
print(b) # prints 10

txt2 = "Hula loops are fun."
txt3 = list(txt2)
xy = txt3[a:b]
z = ""
for item in xy:
    
    z = z + item

print(z)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).